# after summerising my model theres none in the input shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have this model:

```
 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                               input_shape=(96, 96, 1),
                              kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-7),
                  loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics =['accuracy'])
```

the model works, trained well and everything, but when I try to predict I get a weird shape, as you can see in the image below
[image]

why do I have a none, my shape is (96,96,1), how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to fix, the `None` in the batch dimension implies that this dimension is variable sized. This makes sense since the model can be trained using any batch size.

Comment: ok thanks, that did not solve my issue, but at least I know its not a problem here